# How to read the value of `CommandLineArgument` from `launchSettings.json` using `ConfigurationBuilder()`?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, configuration

Your comments and your mentoring are much appreciated!

### The Setting

- c# (net7.0)
- console application
- NuGet-Package: Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
- NuGet-Package: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
- NuGet-Package: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting
- configuration file: launchSettings.json

### The Goal

My goal is to store the `args` in a custom designed class, while using dependency injection and configuration tools provided by Microsoft.

### The Problem

In `Program` the content of `args` is as expected.
If I iterate over the array `args`, I have access to the members stored in `launchSettings.json`. The first member stores the `key` and the second member stores the `value` of `"--CommandLineArgument CommandLineStringIsPassedOnByLaunchSettingsJson"`.
If I use the code `builder.Build().GetValue<string>("CommandLineArgument")`, I receive the correct value.

In `Startup` the content of `CommandLineArgument` is `string.empty`. I would expect the value *CommandLineStringIsPassedOnByLaunchSettingsJson*.

[image: Screenshot of Console Output]

### The Question

What am I missing here?
Did I miss something in the configuration part?
Do I use incorrect code in `GetAppSetting`?
I am assuming these two code lines do the same - is this correct?:
`builder.Build().GetValue<string>("CommandLineArgument")`
`_configuration.GetValue<string>("CommandLineArgument")`

### The Unabridged Code

The configuration file `launchSetting.json`.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "StackOverflow": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--CommandLineArgument CommandLineStringIsPassedOnByLaunchSettingsJson",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

`Program`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using StackOverflow;

var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
    .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
    .AddEnvironmentVariables()
    .AddCommandLine(args);

Console.WriteLine($"\n*** Program.Main() ***");
foreach (var item in args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Commandline Argument (collection of 'args'): {item}");
}

using var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddTransient<IStartup, Startup>();
        services.AddTransient<IAppSettingProvider, AppSettingProvider>();
    })
    .Build();

using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

Console.WriteLine($"Commandline Argument ('Build().GetValue()'): {builder.Build().GetValue<string>("CommandLineArgument")}");

services.GetRequiredService<IStartup>().Run();

Console.WriteLine($"\n***** Press ENTER To End The Application *****");
Console.ReadLine();
```

`IAppSettingProvider`

```
namespace StackOverflow;

public interface IAppSettingProvider
{
    AppSetting GetAppSetting();
}
```

`AppSettingProvider`

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

namespace StackOverflow;

public class AppSettingProvider : IAppSettingProvider
{
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public AppSettingProvider(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public AppSetting GetAppSetting()
    {
        AppSetting output = new()
        {
            CommandLineArgument = _configuration.GetValue<string>("CommandLineArgument")!,
        };

        return output;
    }
}
```

`IStartup`

```
namespace StackOverflow;

public interface IStartup
{
    void Run();
}
```

`Startup`

```
namespace StackOverflow;

public class Startup : IStartup
{
    public AppSetting AppSetting { get; set; }

    readonly IAppSettingProvider _appSettingProvider;

    public Startup(IAppSettingProvider appSettingProvider)
    {
        _appSettingProvider = appSettingProvider;

        AppSetting = new();
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\n*** {nameof(Startup)}.{nameof(Run)}() ***");
        Console.WriteLine($"The value of the command line: {AppSetting.CommandLineArgument}");

        AppSetting = _appSettingProvider.GetAppSetting();
        Console.WriteLine($"The value of the command line: {AppSetting.CommandLineArgument}");

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

`AppSetting`

```
namespace StackOverflow;

public class AppSetting
{
    public string CommandLineArgument { get; set; } = "default Value";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Option #1

Add the `args` parameter to the `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` method.

```cs
using var host =
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) // <-- add args here
        .ConfigureServices(
            (context, services) =>
            {
                services.AddTransient<IStartup, Startup>();
                services.AddTransient<IAppSettingProvider, AppSettingProvider>();
            }
        )
        .Build();
```

This way it will be available through the `IConfiguration` interface.

## Option #2

I suggest using the `IOptions` feature instead of a manually written `AppSettingProvider`.

**`AppSetting.cs`** - it is the same as yours

```cs
namespace StackOverflow;

public class AppSetting
{
    public string CommandLineArgument { get; set; } = "default Value";
}
```

The configuration key will be `AppSetting:CommandLineArgument` but you can use double underscore as well: `AppSetting__CommandLineArgument`.

**`launchSettings.json`**

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "StackOverflow": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--AppSetting__CommandLineArgument CommandLineStringIsPassedOnByLaunchSettingsJson",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then in `Program.cs` register the options.

**`Program.cs`**

```cs
using var host =
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args) // <-- add args here
        .ConfigureServices(
            (context, services) =>
            {
                // register your settings as options
                services
                    .AddOptions<AppSetting>()
                    .Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSetting));

                services.AddTransient<IStartup, Startup>();
            }
        )
        .Build();
```

Then you inject it into you `Startup`.

**`Startup.cs`**

```cs
namespace StackOverflow;

public class Startup : IStartup
{
    private readonly AppSetting appSetting;

    public Startup(IOptions<AppSetting> appSettingOptions)
    {
        appSetting = appSettingOptions.Value;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\n*** {nameof(Startup)}.{nameof(Run)}() ***");

        Console.WriteLine(
            $"The value of the command line: {appSetting.CommandLineArgument}"
        );

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

## Option #3

This will be same as **Option #2** but without the need to specify `AppSetting__` prefix in the command line.

**`launchSettings.json`**

```json
{
  "profiles": {
    "StackOverflow": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--CommandLineArgument CommandLineStringIsPassedOnByLaunchSettingsJson",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**`Program.cs`**

```cs
using var host =
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder() // <-- do not add args here
        .ConfigureAppConfiguration(
            configurationBuilder =>
            configurationBuilder.AddCommandLine(
                args, // <-- add args here
                new Dictionary<string, string>()
                {
                    ["--CommandLineArgument"] = "AppSetting:CommandLineArgument"
                }
            )
        )
        .ConfigureServices(
            (context, services) =>
            {
                // register your settings as options
                services
                    .AddOptions<AppSetting>()
                    .Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSetting));

                services.AddTransient<IStartup, Startup>();
            }
        )
        .Build();
```

Comment: That simple! Thanks @Gabor for sharing options how to solve my issue. This is adding some tools to my toolbox. One question does pop up, right a way: what is `.AddCommandLine(args)` used for?

Comment: After checking out the different options, I can specify my additional question: when is `ConfigurationBuilder` used? In my code it does not have any purpose, doen't it? Can I add `appsettings.json` somewhere in `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`?

Comment: `Host.CreateDefaultBuilder()` uses a `ConfigurationBuilder` internally to which you can add multiple types of config sources e.g. using `ConfigureAppConfiguration()`. `ConfigurationBuilder` loads all the config sources and builds key-value pairs from them. The host builder adds some config sources by default. The space is very limited here, so I suggest reading the [Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/) and [Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options) topics in ASP.NET Core Fundamentals.

Comment: As for your code, you indeed don't need to create a `ConfigurationBuilder` manually. As for `appsettings.json` file, the host builder by default loads it and also `appsettings.EnvironmentName.json` file as well where `EnvironmentName` is determined from environment variables (`DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT` or `ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT`) or command line arguments (e.g. `environment`). If nowhere specified then it will be `Production` by default, so `appsettings.Production.json` file will be loaded, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comments, I was able to add some knowledge to my (basic) coding skills!

One thing is, to keep in my what pre-configured defauls `CreateDefaultBuilder` is providing. If I stick to these defaults, there is no need to implement `ConfigurationBuilder`.
A second learing is, not to forget to update the properties of the setting-files like `appsettings.json`. It is no wonder that my settings are not read, if I forgot to tell VisualStudio to copy these files.
The third thing I have learned is to use `IOptions<>`. That is a huge progress to me.

### My updated code

The classes `IAppSettingProvider` and `AppSettingProvider` have been removed.

The setting file `launchSetting.json`.
The key was updated to `AppSetting:CommandLineArgument`.

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "StackOverflow": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "commandLineArgs": "--AppSetting:CommandLineArgument CommandLineStringIsPassedOnByLaunchSettingsJson",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "DOTNET_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The setting file `appsettings.json`.
I have added this for understanding the pre-configured defaults. Don't forget to tell VS to copy this file!

```
{
  "FileSetting": {
    "ContractFile": "ContractsDevelopment.csv",
    "ContractorFile": "ContractorsDevelopment.csv",
    "ClientFile": "ClientsDevelopment.csv",
    "FulfillmentFile": "FulfillmentsDevelopment.csv",
    "Directory": "MyDevelopmentFiles"
  }
}
```

The setting file for production environment `appsettings.Production.json`.
I have added this for understanding the pre-configured defaults. Don't forget to tell VS to copy this file!

```
{
  "FileSetting": {
    "ContractFile": "ContractsProduction.csv",
    "ContractorFile": "ContractorsProduction.csv",
    "ClientFile": "ClientsProduction.csv",
    "FulfillmentFile": "FulfillmentsProduction.csv",
    "Directory": "MyProductionFiles"
  }
}
```

`Program`
Since I understood `ConfigurationBuilder` was not needed in my example, it was clear to pass forward the `args` in this place `CreateDefaultBuilder(args)`.
Added `AddOptions<myClass>` to the dependency injection.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using StackOverflow;

Console.WriteLine($"\n*** Program.Main() ***");
foreach (var item in args)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Commandline Argument (iteration of 'args'): {item}");
}

using var host = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        services.AddOptions<AppSetting>().Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection(AppSetting.Key));
        services.AddOptions<FileSetting>().Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection(FileSetting.Key));
        services.AddTransient<IStartup, Startup>();
    })
    .Build();

using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

services.GetRequiredService<IStartup>().Run();

Console.WriteLine($"\n***** Press ENTER To End The Application *****");
Console.ReadLine();
```

`IStartup`

```
namespace StackOverflow;

public interface IStartup
{
    void Run();
}
```

`Startup`
Replaced `IConfiguration<myClass>` with `IOptions<myClass>`.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;

namespace StackOverflow;

public class Startup : IStartup
{
    public AppSetting AppSetting { get; private set; }
    public FileSetting FileSetting { get; private set; }

    private readonly IOptions<AppSetting> _optionsAppSetting;
    private readonly IOptions<FileSetting> _optionsFileSetting;

    public Startup(IOptions<AppSetting> optionsAppSetting, IOptions<FileSetting> optionsFileSetting)
    {
        _optionsAppSetting = optionsAppSetting;
        _optionsFileSetting = optionsFileSetting;

        AppSetting = _optionsAppSetting.Value;
        FileSetting = _optionsFileSetting.Value;
    }

    public void Run()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"\n*** {nameof(Startup)}.{nameof(Run)}() ***");
        Console.WriteLine($"The value of the command line: {AppSetting.CommandLineArgument}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The value: {FileSetting.ClientFile}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The value: {FileSetting.ContractFile}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The value: {FileSetting.ContractorFile}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The value: {FileSetting.FulfillmentFile}");
        Console.WriteLine($"The value: {FileSetting.Directory}");

        Console.WriteLine("\nPress ENTER to continue.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

`AppSetting`
Added `Key` to the class. Found this on *learn.Microsoft.com*. Not sure if this is adding any real value to the code. This `const` is used in `Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection(AppSetting.Key))` instead of `Bind(context.Configuration.GetSection(nameof(AppSetting)))`.

```
namespace StackOverflow;

public sealed class AppSetting
{
    public const string Key = nameof(AppSetting);
    public string CommandLineArgument { get; set; } = "default Value";
}
```

`FileSetting`

```
namespace StackOverflow;

public sealed class FileSetting
{
    public const string Key = nameof(FileSetting);
    public string ContractFile { get; set; } = "default";
    public string ContractorFile { get; set; } = "default";
    public string ClientFile { get; set; } = "default";
    public string FulfillmentFile { get; set; } = "default";
    public string Directory { get; set; } = "default";
}
```